# Does boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> close connection once destroyed?

Tags: c++, thrift

I have a small code snippet that uses [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) for network communications.

```
int main() {
  while (true) {
    boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
    boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
    boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

    CalculatorClient client(protocol);

    try {
      transport->open();

      client.ping();
      cout << "ping()" << endl;

      // following line is commented out intentionally
      //transport->close();
    } catch (TException& tx) {
      cout << "ERROR: " << tx.what() << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: Does boost::shared_ptr close connection once destroyed? If yes, then `transport->close();` can be commented out without any problems, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TTransport.h;h=d06b0f8829cb2195439587bde136f006bd2257bc;hb=HEAD), I don't see TTransport doing anything in its destructor. However, the destructor of TSocket ([src](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp;h=8f0f06ca8481d7b132da974b61de09b1e8a4d7a9;hb=HEAD)), does call it's close() function.

Since the shared_ptr was created in the scope of your main function and no one else has asked for a pointer to the object in care of the shared_ptr, 'socket' will destruct after it goes out of scope.

[TBufferedTransport](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TVirtualTransport.h;h=0cacf61d0b71df371e9a69f473c140825ac9c151;hb=HEAD) does not appear to explictly declare a destructor, however, it does own a TSocket, which will got out of scope when TBufferedTransport destructs, thus the TSocket's destructor gets called.

TBufferedTransport::[rBuf_/wBuf_] are scoped_arrays so I don't think you need to worry about those either.

Comment: Yeah, I have just looked at the source code and found the same thing. Thanks!